# can a restful URL consist if "?" symbol?

Tags: facebook, api, rest, twitter

I have read in so many places that a restful urls should identify rresources with slash separated names as follows

```
http://www.example.com/customers/33245/orders
http://www.example.com/customers/33245/orders/8769/lineitems
```

Twitter claims that it has a restful api.But some of its api urls contains "?".

```
 https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40twitterapi
```

even facebook api urls have "?". so can these apis called as restful apis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URL containing a query string (the "?" and everything that follows) has nothing to do with whether an API is restful or not. Query strings are a part of a URL that define resources for this media type. Whether the identifier for the resource is in the query string or in the path of the URL doesn't matter.

Very few APIs are restful as defined by Roy Fielding's [dissertation on the REST architecture](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/fielding_dissertation.pdf). Roy even made a point of this in 2008 with a [blog article](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/fielding_dissertation.pdf) addressing the most serious violations.

There are aesthetic and SEO concerns for preferring one over the other. But both ways can be restful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, restful addresses are URIs which may contain query parameters. There are best practices but nothing says a restful API may not have a '?'

Comment: but twitter could have made those query parameters slash separated to make it more restful. why didn't they?

Comment: Having query parameters doesn't make it any less restful. Often times optional values are placed in the query parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the parameters used for directly identifying resources are stated as path parameters separated by /

```
http://www.example.com/customers/33245/orders
http://www.example.com/customers/33245/orders/8769/lineitems
```

If a resource may be displayed in several ways, e.g. language, one could state the language as a query parameter:

```
http://www.example.com/customers/33245/orders?lang=fr
```